# Moving communities from QA to Production

Tags: community, deployment, eclipse, data-export

I have created a site in our QA enviornment with contents, articles with zones, chatter with categories and various permission sets based on profile including branding. I would now like to move this to production. Is there a way to import the site to production with all the contents and data? Or should I need to recreate it on production once again?

Comment: Any answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is feasible with the Force.com Migration Tool. A good link is [here](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/migration-using-ant-in-salesforce/). A downside is that this is relatively complicated and there are no audits, unlike with Change Sets.

As per the [Change Sets documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_components.htm&language=en), it is feasible to move Communities (Zones) and Permission Sets to Production. It looks like enabling Chatter and corresponding categories will have to be made manually.

A good start point to refer to Change Sets can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets.htm&language=en).

Thanks